# Using lots of Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an asp.net app and I'm realizing that for a specific functionality I'm using a lot of `Task.Factory.StartNew();` and these tasks in turn trigger other tasks, something like this:

```
public void StartTheWork()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething1());       
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething2());
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething3());
}
```

This method is called every 2 hours; it's basically a worker method. It all seems to work on my local machine but I'm wondering what risk I'm taking with lots of tasks running simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest risk once deployed is the application pool recycling while the tasks are running:

> So why isn’t this a problem for your typical per request ASP.NET code? When ASP.NET tears down the AppDomain, it will attempt to flush the existing requests and give them time to complete before it takes down the App Domain. ASP.NET and IIS are considerate to code that they know is running, such as code that runs as part of a request.
>   **Problem is, ASP.NET doesn’t know about work done on a background thread spawned using a timer or similar mechanism. It only knows about work associated with a request**.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/